# Change copy and paste shortcuts for Terminal in VS Code Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu and by default, shortcuts for copy and past in Terminal are Ctrl + Shift + C and Ctrl + Shift + V. Is there any way to change these combinations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click the [image: settings] icon in the bottom left corner of VSCode.
2. Click "Keyboard Shortcuts".
3. Type "Terminal: Copy" in the search bar.
4. Click the pencil icon and enter your preferred keyboard shortcut
   [image]
5. Repeat by searching for `Terminal: Paste`